# Perl remove item from array if selected a certain number of times

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of strings and a subroutine that randomly selects one of the items from the array and continues to do so. My problem is that I want to remove an element from the array if it has already been picked 5 times.

Here is a simple example:

```
@list = ('A' .. 'Z'); #Create array composing of A-Z

while(@list) { # While @list is not empty
    my $pick = $list[rand @list];
    print $pick . "\n";
    ### REMOVE $PICK FROM @LIST AFTER $PICK HAS BEEN SELECTED 5 TIMES ###
}

### WILL EXIT LOOP ONCE EACH LETTER HAS BEEN PICKED 5 TIMES ###
```

Comment: Do you have to use an array? It might be easier to use a hash where the letters A through Z are the keys and the number of times picked are the values.

Comment: Well the A-Z was just a simple example. My actual use is that I load a file in as an array `open ($fhi, "rand.txt"); my @list = $fhi->getlines;`

Comment: You can load that into a hash with `my %lines = map { $_ => 0 } $fh->getlines;`, but ikegami has already given a nice solution using arrays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use the following: (This is an O(N) solution)

```
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

for my $pick (shuffle((@list) x 5)) {
   ...
}
```

To really remove it from the array: (This is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) solution)

```
my %counts = map { $_ => 0 } @list;

while (@list) {
   my $pick = $list[rand(@list)];

   if ($counts{$pick}++ == 5) {
      delete($counts{$pick});
      @list = keys(%counts);
   }

   ...
}
```

---

Why the second solution is O(N<sup>2</sup>):

N-1 elements are copied the first time `@list = keys(%counts);` is executed.

N-2 elements are copied the second time `@list = keys(%counts);` is executed.

...

1 element is copied the second last time `@list = keys(%counts);` is executed.

0 elements are copied the last time `@list = keys(%counts);` is executed.

O( (N-1)+(N-2)+...+1+0 )

= O( N(N-1)/2 ) [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

= O( N<sup>2</sup>/2 - N/2 )

= O(N<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: I did not realize but I had the solution mostly in front of me. I was running my code @ 5 threads so the subroutine was already being run 5 times at once. All I had to do was use `my $pick = shift(@list)` instead of multiplying @list x5. I chose yours as an answer since it would work in any normal circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep track of each letter's count.  For that, you'll need a hash.

Each time through the loop, you'll pick a letter.  If you've picked it 5 times, then delete it from the hash of possibilities.  After all the letters have been deleted, you're done.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %letters = map { ($_ => 1) } 'A' ..'C';

my $maxpicks = 5;
while ( keys %letters ) {
    my @possibilities = keys %letters;

    my $pick = $possibilities[ rand @possibilities ];
    print "I picked $pick\n";
    if ( ++$letters{$pick} >= $maxpicks ) {
        print "Deleting $pick after being picked $maxpicks times\n";
        delete $letters{$pick};
    }
}


I picked B
I picked A
I picked B
I picked A
I picked A
I picked B
I picked C
I picked C
I picked A
Deleting A after being picked 5 times
I picked B
Deleting B after being picked 5 times
I picked C
I picked C
Deleting C after being picked 5 times
```

Comment: Slightly more efficient to populate `@possibilities` on delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the number of times that a letter has been selected using a hash then filter out the elements that have been chosen 5 times with [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my @letters = ('A' .. 'Z');

my %seen_letters; 
while ( @letters ) {
    my $pick = $letters[rand @letters];

    print $pick . "\n";
    if ( ++$seen_letters{$pick} == 5 ) {
       @letters = grep { $_ ne $pick } @letters;
       delete $seen_letters{$pick};
    }
}
```